# Show custom error message on passwordless Auth0 page

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

I would like to only allow certain phone numbers when patients sign up to my application through a passwordless Auth0 page.

For this I added a custom Auth0 action to the *Pre User Registration* flow.

My custom action checks the phone prefix:

```js
/**
* Handler that will be called during the execution of a PreUserRegistration flow.
*
* @param {Event} event - Details about the context and user that is attempting to register.
* @param {PreUserRegistrationAPI} api - Interface whose methods can be used to change the behavior of the signup.
*/
exports.onExecutePreUserRegistration = async (event, api) => {
  if (!isAllowedPhoneNumber(event.user.phone_number)) {
    api.access.deny('my_custom_identifier', 'My Custom Message');
  }
};

const allowedPhonePrefixes = ["+43", "+32", "+420", "+45"];

const isAllowedPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber) =>
  allowedPhonePrefixes.some((prefix) => phoneNumber.startsWith(prefix));
```

However, "My Custom Message" doesn't show up when I try a phone number outside those allowed. Instead, I see the default "We're sorry, something went wrong".

I then tried to edit the HTML code of my custom Auth0 login page adding this:

```js
languageDictionary = {
  ...languageDictionary,
  passwordless: {
    "lock.fallback": "My Custom Message",
    "no_signups_from_outside_schengen_area": "My Custom Message 2",
  }
};
```

So the HTML code of my page now looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Sign In with Auth0</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>

  <!--[if IE 8]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ie8/0.2.5/ie8.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/base64.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/11.30/lock.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Decode utf8 characters properly
    var config = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob('@@config@@'))));
    config.extraParams = config.extraParams || {};
    var connection = config.connection;
    var prompt = config.prompt;
    var languageDictionary;
    var language;

    if (config.dict && config.dict.signin && config.dict.signin.title) {
      languageDictionary = { title: config.dict.signin.title };
    } else if (typeof config.dict === 'string') {
      language = config.dict;
    }
    var loginHint = config.extraParams.login_hint;

      languageDictionary = {
        ...languageDictionary,
        passwordless: {
          "lock.fallback": "My Custom Message",
          "no_signups_from_outside_schengen_area": "My Custom Message 2",
        }
      };

    var lock = new Auth0LockPasswordless(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
      auth: {
        redirectUrl: config.callbackURL,
        responseType: (config.internalOptions || {}).response_type ||
          (config.callbackOnLocationHash ? 'token' : 'code'),
        params: config.internalOptions
      },
      configurationBaseUrl: config.clientConfigurationBaseUrl,
      overrides: {
        __tenant: config.auth0Tenant,
        __token_issuer: config.authorizationServer.issuer
      },
      assetsUrl:  config.assetsUrl,
      allowedConnections: connection ? [connection] : null,
      rememberLastLogin: !prompt,
      language: language,
      languageBaseUrl: config.languageBaseUrl,
      languageDictionary: languageDictionary,
      theme: {
        logo:            'https://link-to-my-logo.something',
        primaryColor:    '#429db3'
      },
      closable: false,
      showTerms: false
    });

    lock.show();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

... but still neither "My Custom Message" nor "My Custom Message 2" show up. I still see "We're sorry, something went wrong".

---

How can I show a custom error message to users who enter a phone number from outside the list of allowed countries?

Note: I am pretty sure that the custom Auth0 action works, as I am able to prevent sign-ups for certain phone prefixes. What is probably wrong is the way I'm changing the code of the HTML page shown above, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There is a partial solution that allows to show a custom message for *all* extensibility errors. (I haven't found a way to show different custom messages for different extensibility errors.)

This partial solution involves changing the structure in which the `languageDictorionary` variable above is structured:

```js
languageDictionary = {
  ...languageDictionary,
  error: {
    passwordless: {
      extensibility_error: "My Custom Message for all extensibility errors"
    }
  }
};
```

This way, any call to `api.access.deny` in the *Pre User Registration flow* will show "My Custom Message for all extensibility errors", no matter what identifier or message is passed to `api.access.deny`.